# Crystal Report Self Joins

Tags: mysql, crystal-reports

I'm trying to put a report together using Crystal Reports. I have to display a list of "class numbers" and the description of those classes. If there are prerequisites for those classes, I need to list those (the class number) as well as a description/title.

Currently I am able to display everything but the prerequisite descriptions. I believe I have to preform a self join since I'm only using one table. What I've done so far is use the command option when entering the tables I want to use for the report. In that command I have

```
SELECT Main.prerequisite, Sub.course_no, Sub.description
FROM course Main
JOIN course Sub ON Main.prerequisite = Sub.course_no
where main.prerequisite is not null
```

The table is called "course" while the columns are "course_no", "description", "prerequisite".

Anytime I add "description" to the report, it only gives me the course_no's corresponding description, not the prerequisite description.

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong or what I'm not doing at all, but any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: I didn't understand the use of self join? without self join also I am sure you will get what you required.

Comment: My issue may be in how I go about using it in Crystal Reports. When I use a self join in SQL I indeed get what I need. However, when I try using it in Crystal, I get the prerequisite numbers, but not their descriptions.

Comment: I'm a little confused as to what the problem is. The table generated from your SQL Command _should_ be displaying the `description` that goes along with the `course_no` as both of those columns are coming from the same copy of the `course` table (the table aliased as `Sub`)...

Comment: The issue is that I also need to display the description of the prerequisite column. Currently it is only displaying the course_no's description

Answer (score 0):

I figured a work around and thought I should post it here. Hopefully to avoid wasting anyone's time as well as providing my solution to anyone that may have a similar issue.

I simply created a view in SQL

```
Create view preReqs AS
SELECT Main.course_no AS [course_no]
,Main.description AS [description]
,Main.prerequisite AS [prerequisite]
,Sub.description AS [preReqDescription]
FROM course As Main
LEFT OUTER JOIN course As Sub ON Main.prerequisite = Sub.course_no
```

After I created that, I just imported the view instead of the table itself into the Crystal Report. I was then able to group by whatever I wished.

Hopefully this will help anyone else that may run into this issue.  Thank you for everyone that provided their time/input as well. I appreciate it.